# how can i protect my website

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, code-injection

I created my website using asp.net . I used ado.net for executing insert , update , delete functions in my database (sqlserver 2005 ) . My database is attacked by hacker . 
every record my tables is injected by data like this

```
</title><style>.as9y{position:absolute;clip:rect(441px,auto,auto,441px);}</style><div class=as9y>secured <a href=http://5mincashadvance.com >payday loans</a></div>
```

so please help me about how can i prevent this spam injects ..

this is example of insert function

```
myStatic.insertFields("Name, Phone, Mail, Title, Body", " U_Complaint", "'" + txtName.Text
            + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "','" + txtmail.Text + "','" + txtTitle.Text + "','" + txtBody.Text + "'");
```

so there is any error in this code .. if not whats wrong ....

Comment: did you validate ALL input before feeding it to insertFields? If not, there is your well-documented problem called sql-injection. See related topics to the right!

Comment: Use [`SQL-Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent [sql-injection](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/30/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks.aspx). Use an [Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) to prevent [cross-site-scripting](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Scripting).

Comment: That is not the actual code that does the insert. The code that does the acutal insert is the code that uses the SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc classes. For starters you should add values by using parameters with SqlCommand.

Comment: yes i validated my input . and now i am changing my code . for using sql-parameters . i use ckeditor in my website . there is any problem if i used this tool

Comment: any one help me whats the meaning of Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library and how can i used it for protect my site

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ckeditor the value you get is the html with formating which is getting saved inyour db. see here http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7892 to know more

Answer (score 0):

Dont insert data without using sql parameters instead of validate enteries for to prevent sql injections.

Here is sample

```
SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("insert into table1 (columns1,columns2) values (@columns1,@columns2)",sqlCon);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columns",value);
```